# Add the "Save to Drive" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-cloud-platform

I read this document: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive. But I found that it is not possible to create custom buttons, only the buttons provided by Google can be used. What I want to ask is how to create custom buttons.

Comment: Please share what you have been trying so far (cose)